# Commit update before raising error in trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle10g

I am writing an after update trigger to log the username and time of updates to a specific column. 
I need the update to commit and then a message displayed to the user to advise them to do something else. 
I am unable to use dbms_output.put_line as the application hides these messages from the user (changing the aplication is impossible as its a third party application and licensing issues prevent any changes). I have tried using raise_application_error which displays the message but because it is raising an error it prevents the update from commiting.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to present a message to the user in real time without changing the application.  If you hold all the users' email addresses I suppose the trigger could send them an email telling them what they need to do?

Comment: I think this will be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

there is a nasty workaround, if there is no other alternative.
In the Trigger you can first submit a job (dbms_job.submit)  and make an update within the job. And then raise an error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you're right it is a rather nasty workaround. i think emailing the user is a neater way to deal with it.

Comment: If the transaction is rolled back the job will not be executed. (Unless you commit the job submission in an autonomous transaction)